# Table Per Subclass Versus Duplicate Columns

Tags: hibernate

In my application, I have this hierarchy:

- LastUser
- LastUserUpdatedTimestamp

The BaseObject is a @MappedSuperclass, which is extended by Transaction, which in turn is extended by SubTransaction.

The Transaction object is defined as such:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TRANSACTION")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Transaction extends BaseObject implements Serializable {
    //etc
}
```

The SubTransaction looks like this:

```
// Primary key join columns
public class SubTransaction extends Transaction implements Serializable {
```

Transaction and SubTransaction are mapped to tables that each have audit columns (yes, identical names)

- LastUser
- LastUpdatedTimestamp

When I try to persist a SubTransaction, an exception is thrown regarding the Transaction's audit columns being null.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you have a tablestructure like

```
   BaseObjectTable
  /               \
 \/               \/
Transaction     Subtransaction
```

but the mapping suggests him

```
BaseObjectTable
  /
 \/
Transaction
  /
 \/
Subtransaction
```

to achieve the first you can try to set `@Extends(BaseObject)` on the Subtransaction